# KeyError: 0 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

waste['GDP ($M)'] - my column in a table
Table 'waste' consist of 161 rows
Error is on the 3 line (with condition). It the table 'True" values are exist, but I can't understand where is the problem.
What should I change in my code?

Also, I changed values in a table from Scientific Notation to float, due to this my NaN values changed to "nan"

```
column = pd.isna(waste['GDP ($M)'])
gdp_nan = []
for row in range(len(waste)):
    if column[row] == True:
        gdp_nan.insert(row, row)
print(gdp_nan)
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see the index starts from 2, I don't know you constraint but change range(len(waste)) as range(2, len(waste)) shuld solve it.What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There was first statement isna(), so by this statement column is boolean. I tried to record all indexes, where GDP is "NaN" value. Thanks, because of your advice, I solved my problem.

Comment: In you case `gdp_nan.insert(row, row)` won't place the value at the desired index, you can change it as `gdp_nan.append(row)`. To use `insert` you have to create a non-empty list, it will replace the value in the desired position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said in the comments, change range(2, len(waste))
Then, I had KeyError 21, which means that 21 record doesn't exist.
You should reindex your dataframe.

```
waste = waste.reset_index(drop = True)
```

right in this way, then loop will work well